# Pass worker service logger to helper classes with dotnet 6

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

I'm working with .NET 6 Worker Services and Serilog.

I have a few services registered in DI like

```cs
// Program.cs
services.AddHostedService<ServiceA>();
services.AddHostedService<ServiceB>();
services.AddHostedService<ServiceC>();

services.AddScoped<FooHelper>();
```

And each of their CTORs looks like

```cs
// ServiceA.cs
public ServiceA(ILogger<ServiceA> logger) => _logger = logger;
```

And my serilog config is

```json
// appsettings.json
"Name": "Logger",
"Args": {
  "configureLogger": {
    "Filter": [
      {
        "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
        "Args": {
          "expression": "SourceContext = 'Foo.ServiceA'"
        }
      }
    ]
...
```

I have 3 loggers setup this way, one for each service.

The problem I'm having is if I have another injected dependency on my service that also takes a logger, then its logs are ignored due to my filters below... I would like to simply re-use the calling service's ILogger instead of having each class create their own.

Another dependency looks like:

```cs
// FooHelper.cs
class FooHelper
{
  readonly ILogger<FooHelper> _logger;
  public FooHelper(ILogger<FooHelper> logger) => _logger = logger;
}
```

Adding this dependency to a service looks like:

```cs
// ServiceA.cs
class ServiceA
{
  readonly ILogger<ServiceA> _logger;
  readonly FooHelper _helper;
  public ServiceA(ILogger<ServiceA> logger, FooHelper helper)
  {
    _logger = logger;
    _helper = helper;
  }
}
```

Comment: simple way would just make helper.Logger public, then in the contructor set helper.Logger = logger; Why do you have so many loggers and filters?

Comment: @Train `Helper` is part of the DI and resolved when needed from the services container. It's never manually constructed, unless I misunderstood you? Also, 3 loggers, one for each service. Each service is doing something different than the others, and didn't want a convoluted single log file.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make the `FooHelper` generic. Depending on your logging-DI-setup you might still get a separate logger, but it still should behave as you want it to.

```
class FooHelper<T>
{
  readonly ILogger<T> _logger;
  public FooHelper(ILogger<T> logger) => _logger = logger;
}

class ServiceA
{
  readonly ILogger<ServiceA> _logger;
  readonly FooHelper _helper;
  public ServiceA(ILogger<ServiceA> logger, FooHelper<ServiceA> helper)
  {
    _logger = logger;
    _helper = helper;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't think that will work since during DI you need to specify a type `T`, which is unknown at that time.

Comment: You'd need to register FooHelper as open generic, e.g. services.AddTransient(typeof(FooHelper<>))`